# SQL - querying without duplicate base on another column, /improving condition.?

Tags: sql

I have written a query which involves joins and finally returns the below result,

```
Name   ID
AAA    1
BBB    1
BBB    6
CCC   1
CCC   6
DDD   6
EEE    1
```

But I want my result to be still filtered in such a way that, the duplicate values in the first column should be ignored which has lesser value. ie, CCC and BBB which are duplicates with value 1 should be removed. The result should be

```
AAA    1
BBB    6
CCC   6
DDD   6
EEE    1
```

Note: I have a condition called `Where (ID = '6' or ID = '1')`, is there any way to improve this condition saying `Where ID = 6 or ID = 1` (if no 6 is available in that table)"

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will likely want to add:

```
GROUP BY name
```

to the bottom of your query and change `ID` to `MAX(ID)` in your `SELECT` statement

It is hard to give a more specific answer without seeing the query you've already written.